# How to use a batch file so that results remain visible on completion

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I run batch files and they exit immediately. I dont want that to happen so that i can see my output. Can someone tell me how to make this happen ?

I use windows 7.

Comment: Up vote the answer which i selected. It is much better and more detailed than the answer by Macke. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding pause is a good answer.  Here are some other ways as well..

Rather than double-clicking on them to execute you can run from a command line:

1. Press the windows key + r  (this opens the "run" window)
2. Type: cmd  into the text input and press enter (or click ok)
3. Change to the directory that contains the batch file, e.g:  cd c:\scripts\foo
4. Execute the batch file by typing it's name and pressing enter, e.g: somename.bat

If there is a lot of output and it scrolls off the screen you can direct the output to a text file instead like so:

somename.bat > output_filename.txt

Then you can open the 'output_filename.txt' file in any text editor to view/search all of the output.  This is better than pause when there more output than what is available in the scrollback.

Comment: somename.bat > output_filename.txt - I saw that the output goes to a file, but the cmd keeps on blinking. I got confused if the execution had really ended or not.

Answer (score 8):

Put this on the very last line of the Batch:

```
cmd /k
```

Comment: For someone who isn't on a Windows machine right now, what does this do?

Comment: CMD /K    Run Command and then return to the CMD prompt.
          This is useful for testing, to examine variables

Answer (score 6):

Add the **pause** command at the end of your batch file. This waits for you to key something in.

*(The nice thing is that if you're running the batch file from a non-interactive process, such as a automated build system or scheduled task, the pause is simply skipped.)*

The help message for **pause** is:

```
C:\>help pause
Suspends processing of a batch program and displays the message
    Press any key to continue . . .
```

If there is lots of output and you can't scroll far enough back, adjust the **screen buffer height** of the command window. This can be done via right-click on the `c:\` icon go to `properties` -> `layout`:

[image]